# Mongoose - replace given collection with given array of documents

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

There is a requirement where I have to fetch a collection (InstituteCourse) into a JavaScript array. After performing certain modifications (update vacantSeats property) to its properties, I need to update the same in MongoDB. However, instead of updating individual documents of InstituteCourse, I want to perform the operation in a single go. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
const allotController = async(req, res) => {
    const instituteCourses = await InstituteCourse.find();
    const students = await Student.find().populate("choices");
    students.sort((s1, s2) => s1.rank-s2.rank);
    const results = [];
    for(student of students){
        student.choices.sort((c1, c2) => c1.preferenceNo - c2.preferenceNo);
        let isAlloted = false;
        let i = 0;
        while(!isAlloted && i<student.choices.length){
            const ic = student.choices[i].instituteCourse;
            const idx = instituteCourses.findIndex((ic2) => ic2._id.toString() == ic._id.toString());
            const vacantSeats = instituteCourses[idx]?.vacantSeats;
            if(vacantSeats>0){
                isAlloted = true;
                const result = new Result({student: student._id, instituteCourse: ic._id});
                results.push(result);
                instituteCourses[idx].vacantSeats--;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    await Result.insertMany(results);
    /*
    // I don't want to update each document
    for(ic of instituteCourses){
        await InstituteCourse.findByIdAndUpdate(ic._id, ic);
    }
    */
    await InstituteCourse.updateMany({}, instituteCourses);  // PROBLEM LIES HERE
    res.json(instituteCourses);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Merge Aggregation stage** for replacing document but not every document only that are changed

refer official documentation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/